# Using RegExp.test for the callback of Array.some

Tags: javascript, regex, callback, built-in

This works:

```js
var animals = ["caterpillar", "dog", "bird"];
var catMatch = /cat/i;
var catFound = animals.some(function(animalName) {
  return catMatch.test(animalName);
});

console.log(catFound);
```

But this doesn't

```js
var animals = ["caterpillar", "dog", "bird"];
var catMatch = /cat/i;
var catFound = animals.some(catMatch.test);

console.log(catFound);
```

Why doesn't the second version work?

Answer (score 2):

`RegExp.prototype.test` depends on its `this` value to work. You can pass the required `this` value to `some`:

```
var catFound = animals.some(catMatch.test, catMatch);
```